# How to pass device information to a SSRS subscription?

Tags: c#, ssrs-2008

My team and I, we're trying to create a subscription and export a report in CSV format, but we need to change the field delimiter from "," (which is the default). How can we pass the device information to a SSRS (2008) subscription programmatically (C#)?

We have a web reference to ReportingServices2005. This is and example of our code:

```
string report = "Insert report here";
string desc = "A description";
string eventType = "TimedSubscription";
string matchData = "<ScheduleDefinition>...</ScheduleDefinition>";
string RenderFormat = "CSV";
ParameterValue[] reportParameters = GetReportParameters();

var extensionParams = new List<ParameterValue>();
extensionParams.Add(new ParameterValue
{
    Name = Constants.EXTENSIONPARAMRENDER_FORMAT,
    Value = RenderFormat
});
extensionParams.Add(new ParameterValue
{
    Name = Constants.EXTENSIONPARAMFILENAME,
    Value = FileName
});
// Insert more params here...

ExtensionSettings extSettings = new ExtensionSettings();
extSettings.ParameterValues = extensionParams.ToArray();
extSettings.Extension = Constants.EXTENSIONREPORTSERVERFILESHARE;

try
{
    ReportingService2005 rs = new ReportingService2005();
    rs.CreateSubscription(
        report, extSettings, desc, eventType, matchData, reportParameters);
}
catch (SoapException e)
{
    // Handle the exception
}
```

We can't find a way to pass the device information, is this even posible?

For more info check:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.wssux.reportingserviceswebservice.rsmanagementservice2005.reportingservice2005.createsubscription%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't pass `DeviceInfo` to the `CreateSubscription()` method, but one of these two approaches may do the trick for you...

1. See [Customizing Rendering Extension Parameters in RSReportServer.Config](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms156281%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) to create a new version of the default "CSV" extension where you can configure the `DeviceInfo` you require. So you could add a section like this in your config file...

   ```
   <Extension Name="CsvPipeDelimited" Type="Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.DataRenderer.CsvReport,Microsoft.ReportingServices.DataRendering">
     <Configuration>
       <DeviceInfo>
         <Extension>txt</Extension>
         <FieldDelimiter>|</FieldDelimiter>
         <NoHeader>false</NoHeader>
       </DeviceInfo>
     </Configuration>
   </Extension>
   ```
2. [Implementing a Rendering Extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms153624%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) is much more involved, but gives you more control.

Once you have your new Rendering Extension, you can pass the name like this...

```
extensionParams.Add(new ParameterValue
{
    Name = "RenderFormat",
    Value = "CsvPipeDelimited"
});
```